# How to find time difference between 2 records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written a query joining multiple tables and looking out for assistance to find time difference between 2 rows of same identifier.

Example: `Row num` is an additional column that I have added to explain better

```
Row num     NodeID  Caption     VolumeID    Caption     DateTime
1.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 10:25 PM
2.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 10:10 PM
3.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 9:55 PM
4.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 9:40 PM
5.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 9:25 PM
6.          2245    SERVERNAME  6545        D:\RAID     10/10/16 9:25 PM
7.          2245    SERVERNAME  7710        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 10:25 PM
8.          2245    SERVERNAME  7710        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 10:10 PM
9.          2245    SERVERNAME  7710        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:55 PM
10.         2245    SERVERNAME  7710        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:40 PM
11.         2245    SERVERNAME  7710        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:25 PM
12.         2245    SERVERNAME  7711        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 10:25 PM
13.         2245    SERVERNAME  7711        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 10:10 PM
14.         2245    SERVERNAME  7711        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:55 PM
15.         2245    SERVERNAME  7711        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:40 PM
16.         2245    SERVERNAME  7711        D:\AFS\G    10/10/16 9:25 PM
17.         2245    SERVERNAME  7712        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 10:25 PM
18.         2245    SERVERNAME  7712        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 10:10 PM
19.         2245    SERVERNAME  7712        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:55 PM
20.         2245    SERVERNAME  7712        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:40 PM
21.         2245    SERVERNAME  7712        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:25 PM
22.         2245    SERVERNAME  7713        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 10:25 PM
23.         2245    SERVERNAME  7713        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 10:10 PM
24.         2245    SERVERNAME  7713        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:55 PM
25.         2245    SERVERNAME  7713        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:25 PM
26.         2245    SERVERNAME  7713        D:\AFS\C    10/10/16 9:40 PM
```

in the above data sample, identifier is Nodeid and volumeid.

Whenever identifier matches, than record with latest timestamp and the record one before that should be compared to determine the difference.

in above example query should be able to match only row number 1 and 2 for nodeid 2245 and volumeid 6545 and output should be 15 mins

Similarly, for nodeid 2245 and volumeid 7710, row number 7 and 8 should be used for calculation.

How can I do this? I tried using with CTE expression but was unable to do. I also tried with sub query but failed.

Can someone help me here to write the query.

Query that I tried:

```
WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage].Datetime) AS rn
    FROM [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage]
)
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, mc.DateTime, mp.Datetime)
FROM    [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage] mc
JOIN    [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage] mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn
```

This throws an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'rn'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'rn'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below script .

```
;WITH  cte_1
as
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID,VolumeID ORDER BY [Datetime] desc) AS rn
    FROM #t
)
SELECT A.NodeID,A.Caption,A.VolumeID,A.Caption1,A.[DateTime]
,CASE DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime])
                    WHEN 0 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10))
                    ELSE CAST(60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, B.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                        REPLICATE(',60', DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime]) - 1) + 
                        + ',' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, A.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                END TimeDifference
FROM cte_1 A
 join cte_1 B
  on A.rn=b.rn-1
   AND A.NodeID=B.NodeID AND A.VolumeID=B.VolumeID
WHERE B.rn=2 --if you dont want to limit ,comment this line
```

**Sample Output :**

[image]

IF you wanted to display all the rows ,but need the time difference only for the first two rows,add an extra case statement like the below script.

```
;WITH  cte_1
as
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID,VolumeID ORDER BY [Datetime] desc) AS rn
    FROM #t
)
SELECT A.NodeID,A.Caption,A.VolumeID,A.Caption1,A.[DateTime]
,CASE WHEN b.rn=2 THEN CASE DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime])
                    WHEN 0 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10))
                    ELSE CAST(60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, B.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                        REPLICATE(',60', DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.[DateTime], A.[DateTime]) - 1) + 
                        + ',' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, A.[DateTime]) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                END ELSE NULL END TimeDifference
FROM cte_1 A
 join cte_1 B
  on A.rn=b.rn-1
   AND A.NodeID=B.NodeID AND A.VolumeID=B.VolumeID
```

**Sample Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use cte in your query instead of main table:

```
WITH CTEViewName AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage].Datetime) AS rn
    FROM [Operations-Orion].[dbo].[VolumeUsage]
)
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, mc.DateTime, mp.Datetime)
FROM    CTEViewName mc
JOIN    CTEViewName mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn + 1
```